# Can I find under which user is a service running via systemctl command?

Tags: systemd

I want to figure out which user is a given service using. `systemctl status` doesn't seem to provide that info

```
sudo systemctl status nginx.service
sudo systemctl status emperor.uwsgi.service
● emperor.uwsgi.service - uWSGI Emperor
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/emperor.uwsgi.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Tue 2020-03-31 11:26:34 UTC; 7min ago
  Process: 31133 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/pipenv run uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 31133 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 31 11:26:34 ip-10-28-34-70.eu-west-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: emperor.uwsgi.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 31 11:26:34 ip-10-28-34-70.eu-west-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start uWSGI Emperor.
```

Is there any way to get this information from `systemctl` or do I need to open the unit file?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `systemctl show` for this:

```
systemctl show -pUser,UID nginx
```

If `User` shows nothing, and `UID` is `[not set]`, the service is running as root, or the owning user in the case of a user service.

Comment: "If User shows nothing, and UID is [not set], the service is running as root, or the owning user in the case of a user service" ... how to find out if a service is a "user service"?

Comment: User services are only listed if `systemctl` talks to the user’s service manager, so you’ll only see user services if you run `systemctl --user show …`. Running user services have a control group under the user slice, so you’ll see `ControlGroup=/user.slice/…` if you ask for `ControlGroup` in addition to `User` and `UID` (systemctl --user show -pUser,UID,ControlGroup …`).

Comment: For some Unix user `lxc` I have a user service `/home/lxc/.config/systemd/user/lxc-user@.service`, and this service is "user-enabled" (`systemctl --user enable lxc-user@my-container.service`) and successfully started, yet its `ControlGroup` is empty.

Comment: Also, I noticed that querying for non-existing services returns output, therefore this could be misinterpreted as some queried service running as root or owning user, yet such service doesn't exist, e.g. `systemctl show -pUser,UID doesntexist` returns `UID=[not set]<LF>User=`.

Comment: @StephenKitt Do you know how I can change the user account for a service ?

Comment: @supi007 see https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#User=